# quantity +to - infinitive

Tags: infinitives

‎1. An IQ higher than 145 to join the group is required.

2.The score to enter the university is low.

3.The altitude to be able to fly drones is below 100 meters.

4.The height to be able to get on the rollercoaster is above 130cm.

5.The height to be allowed to get on the rollercoaster is above 130cm.

6.Researchers say organisations like Mensa need to rethink their membership - they currently require an IQ higher than 148 to join

I'd like to know whether all the six sentences are correct English.

In this case, I used "to infinitive" to describe the quantities IQ, score, altitude, height.

Comment: Your first example is syntactically invalid - the "adverb of purpose" element ***to join the group*** must either ***precede*** or ***follow*** the specified "required condition" (you can't just drop those words ***inside*** the statement ***An IQ higher than 145 is required*** that's being adverbially modified). Some of your other examples are at least *slightly* "suspect" on syntactic grounds, because of the way they simply omit the semantically essential element ***is required*** or similar (which if omitted can simply be contextually assumed, but it's not "syntactically correct")..

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Then do you think this sentence **"Researchers say organisations like Mensa need to rethink their membership - they currently require an IQ higher than 148 to join"** is syntactically wrong as well? I found the above example on an article.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica And does you mean if context is clear, it's okay to omit "required" in such sentences, although syntactically not correct?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the utterance *They currently require an IQ higher than 148 to join* is syntactically invalid (or at the very least, "flawed"). Consider a simpler version of the same construction: *You need a license to drive*. The default parsing of such constructions is that the implied subject of the subordinate infinitive clause *(**to join, to drive**)* is ***the same as*** the subject of the ***main*** verb *(**organisations like Mensa, you**)*. But in *your* example, the (unspecified) subject is "people who want to join Mensa", which isn't really a syntactically valid way to put it.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Do you mean even this sentence **"You need a license to drive"** is wrong due to the syntactical reason?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, do you think that "they currently require an IQ higher than 148 to join _in_" or "_them_" would solve the problem?

Comment: @Jan: No, that doesn't help, since the "subject" of ***to join*** is still unspecified, but pragmatically speaking we ***know*** that subject can't be ***they*** (even though syntactically that's what it ***should*** be).

Comment: @Zenith: No, I certainly don't mean that ***You need a license to drive*** is invalid. In ***my*** example, the implied subject of ***to drive*** is ***you*** (same as the main verb ***need***). That's the "default" way such utterances should be parsed, so it's fine. But if I said ***The company** need a license to drive*, that would be pretty confusing, to say the least. Whose license are we talking about? Syntactically, it should be *the company*, as it would be with, say, *The company need a license **to drill** [for oil on government-owned land].*

Answer (score 1):

All your examples have problems - some of them incurable.

No 1 is clumsy. It would read far better if rewritten as:

> An IQ above (higher than) 145 is required to join the group.

No 2. needs the insertion of **required** after score.

> The score required to enter the university is low.

No 3 presumably is intended to mean that drones may not be flown above 100 metres.   It needs to be completely rewritten.

> The maximum altitude at which drones may be flown is 100 metres.
>   or
>   One hundred metres is the maximum altitude at which drones are permitted to fly.
>   or
>   Drones may not be flown above 100 metres.

Nos 4 & 5 may no sense. If you mean that the roller coaster reaches heights of 130 metres, you need to rephrase your sentences to make this clear.

Comment: 4 & 5 make sense as well, if we use _body height_ instead of _height_. Besides this, they should be rewritten as no. 2 (_The body height required to_).

Comment: @BenA. As you say. I misread the height completely as 130 metres and misunderstood the sense of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. An IQ higher than 145 to join the group is required.

I would change the word order, because the words that modify each other need to be as close as possible:

*An IQ higher than 145 is required to join the group.*

> 2. The score to enter the university is low.

The word "required" is missing, so:

*The score required to enter the university is low.*

> 3. The altitude to be able to fly drones is below 100 meters.

"Able" refers to "possible," but because this is probably a demand from someone, you need to say "allowed," so:

*The maximum altitude allowed to fly drones is 100 meters.*

> 4. The height to be able to get on the rollercoaster  is above 130cm.

To differ between the height of the rollercoaster and a person, you need to say "body height." The height above 130 cm (separate 130 and cm) is required, because you are not just "able to be" above 130 cm, so:

*The body height required to get on the rollercoaster is 130 cm.*

> 5. The height to be allowed to get on the rollercoaster is above 130cm.

If you want to use "allowed", you need to rewrite:

*To be allowed to get on the rollercoaster, you need to be 130 cm or higher.* (You can skip "body height" here, because it's obvious).

or

*You are allowed to get on the rollercoaster only if you are 130 cm or higher.*

> 6. Researchers say organisations like Mensa need to rethink their
>      membership - they currently require an IQ higher than 148 to join.

Here "to join" does not work, because the subject is missing. This could work:

*Researchers say organisations like Mensa need to rethink their
 membership - they currently require **from the candidates to have** an IQ higher than 148 to join.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105203/discussion-on-answer-by-jan-quantity-to-infinitive).